# Map functions changes weapons?

Tags: xbox-one, pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG when I'm taking the marker off of my map I always switch weapons between pimary and secondary.   Is this something that is just a limitation of playing this game with a controller?  The inputs don't seem to be matched with one another yet every time I do this I change weapons. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Xbox or PC? I've noticed that on PC, if you have the map open and press right mouse button to drop a marker, it brings your gun up to aim down the sights.  I believe that for the PC this is a bug at the moment.

Comment: On the most recent update on Xbox (0.5.30) they fixed this issue where you would switch to the melee weapon when zooming in and out at the map. Now this no longer happens

Comment: awesome thanks @ZeroStack I didn't see that in those patch notes it was one of the most annoying things I've ever seen in a game lol.

Comment: @Zissouu glad I could help - converted comment into answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer for OP:

On Xbox, this glitch was resolved in [patch 0.5.3:](https://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/173866-xbox-game-preview-patch-notes-7/)

> Bug fixes
>
> - Players can now use the D-Pad while in the map view without switching melee, pistol, or throwing weapons
> - Removing the marker from the map when pressing (Y) will no longer switch primary/secondary weapons